# Dependencies to install Prometheus 2.32.1 in RHEL 7.9

Tags: rhel7, dependencies, prometheus

I am trying to install prometheus-2.32.1 in RHEL 7.9 in my virtualbox. But I am failing since it says that yum repository does not have the necessary repos. Can anybody tell me what are the dependencies that I should install before installing the aforementioned version of prometheus?

Comment: Please add the error message to your question in a 'code block' so we can help with the error. Normally yum will tell you what repository or package it is looking for.

Comment: Actually I was trying to install following the instructions in this link: https://www.fosstechnix.com/install-prometheus-and-grafana-on-linux-with-node-exporter/ 
it did not show any error until the last step, where it  simply said "failed to run the server".

Comment: Can you copy and paste the command you ran with the error into the question?

Comment: `sudo snap install prometheus`

Here I tried to install snap. which needed dnf to be installed. Furthermore, dnf required epel-release to be installed and I could not install epel-release.

Comment: If you're using RHEL, enabling EPEL is done in a different way: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/epel/#_el7. You said you were following those instructions but nowhere in that guide does it say to use snaps? I would recommend following the guide as you say, at least the first time!